# How I can add bulma.css toggle navbar in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, bulma

I have added bulma.css in my Next.js project and all runs well, but navbar toggle doesn't work because need add some pure javascript code and React doesn't provide pure DOM events

Answer (score 0):

Just add React Lifecycle event and put your code.

ORIGINAL example:

```
import React from "react";

class NavBar extends React.Component {
componentDidMount() {
const $navbarBurgers = Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.querySelectorAll(".navbar-burger"),
  0
);

if ($navbarBurgers.length > 0) {
    // Add a click event on each of them
    $navbarBurgers.forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener("click", () => {
        // Get the target from the "data-target" attribute
        const target = el.dataset.target;
        const $target = document.getElementById(target);

        // Toggle the "is-active" class on both the "navbar-burger" and the "navbar-menu"
        el.classList.toggle("is-active");
        $target.classList.toggle("is-active");
      });
    });
  }
 }
 render() {
  return (
  <nav className="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
    <div className="navbar-brand">
      <a className="navbar-item" href="https://bulma.io">
        <img
          src="https://bulma.io/images/bulma-logo.png"
          width="112"
          height="28"
        />
      </a>

      <a
        role="button"
        className="navbar-burger burger"
        aria-label="menu"
        aria-expanded="false"
        data-target="navbarBasicExample"
      >
        <span aria-hidden="true" />
        <span aria-hidden="true" />
        <span aria-hidden="true" />
      </a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbarBasicExample" className="navbar-menu">
      <div className="navbar-start">
        <a className="navbar-item">Home</a>

        <a className="navbar-item">Documentation</a>

        <div className="navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable">
          <a className="navbar-link">More</a>

          <div className="navbar-dropdown">
            <a className="navbar-item">About</a>
            <a className="navbar-item">Jobs</a>
            <a className="navbar-item">Contact</a>
            <hr className="navbar-divider" />
            <a className="navbar-item">Report an issue</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className="navbar-end">
        <div className="navbar-item">
          <div className="buttons">
            <a className="button is-primary">
              <strong>Sign up</strong>
            </a>
            <a className="button is-light">Log in</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
);
}
}

 export default NavBar;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and in my case I can resolve it adding in the _app component this line

```
import 'bulma/css/bulma.css
```

Comment: that's true, but the question here is how make navbar toggle fuctional, since you need javascript, in that case you can use my above example :)